# FindIndex() removing items from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

when using RTK Query I tried to build a remove and add to favorite feature. I'm having trouble as I can add to the state. but then the remove section, on `.FindIndex()` is always returning -1 Have it incorrectly used this function?

```
 import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  value: false,
  cardFavId: [],
};

export const favouriteSlice = createSlice({
  name: "favourite",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    makeFav: (state, action) => {
      state.value = !state.value;
      state.cardFavId = [...state.cardFavId, action.payload];
    },

    removeFav: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload, "payload remove pressed");
      const index = state.cardFavId.findIndex(
        (cardItem) => cardItem.id === action.payload
      );

      let newCardFav = [...state.cardFavId];
      console.log(`Index Value ${index}`);

      if (index >= 0) {
        //itemCard has been Faved.. remove it.
        newCardFav.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        // Do nothing
        console.warn("Cannot remove as its not been fav ");
      }
      state.cardFavId = newCardFav;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { makeFav, removeFav } = favouriteSlice.actions;

export default favouriteSlice.reducer;
```

[image: err]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `findIndex` callback is incorrect, because you need to compare the item's id to `action.payload.id` and not just the `action.payload`, because `payload` is an object.

Second, an easier way to remove an item from an array (although less efficient sometimes, but it's easier to write) is to go something like

```
state.cardFav = state.cardFav.filter(cardItem => cardItem.id !== action.payload.id)
```

Meaning, you only keep the items with an id that's different than the one you want to delete